# How to detect Class label in Apriori algorithm in MATLAB?

Tags: classification, data-mining

Sorry if my my question is simple. I just would like to know how to detect class labels in data mining algorithms such as Apriori.

As I know, in the normal use of the Apriori algorithm our patterns have no label. Should I use another algorithm or technique?